# Mostrar View como slide

Tags: java, android, animação

Oi, gostaria de saber como faço um View aparecer como slide em um layout android alterando o tamanho de seus irmãos, por exemplo as informações de um ponto no Google Maps app que aparece e mudando o tamanho do mapa.

- A informação estar escondida e o mapa ocupa a tela toda
  [image: A informação estar escondida e o mapa ocupa a tela toda]
- A informação é mostrada e o tamanho do mapa diminui
  [image: A informação é mostrada e o tamanho do mapa diminui]

Comment: Silas, ja tive o mesmo problema que você, porém a única limitação da minha solução é que não consegui fazer o mapa se "ajustar". Isso é, ele ficava com o tamanho reduzido, mas não centrava (na área menor) no mesmo ponto que estava centrado (antes de expandir o conteúdo). Se quiser posso incluir minha solução como resposta.

Comment: Certo, quero ver sua solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou partir do princípio que o conteúdo que fica por trás do painel deslizante não faz parte da pergunta. Apenas a implementação do painel deslizante será abordado.

Na minha solução, fiz o uso da [`Android Sliding Up Panel`](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), que tem como exemplo de aplicação no app [`Umano`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sothree.umano).

Se estiver utilizando o **Maven** ou o **Gradle** para resolver suas dependências, basta incluir essa *library* como uma dependências:

Exemplo usando o `Gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
}
```

Para o perfeito funcionamento, a *library* força uma estrutura em seu layout.

> 1. Inclua o `com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout` como o elemento raiz do seu layout (seja do `Fragment` ou de sua `Activity`).
> 2. O `gravity` (`com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout`) da raiz **precisa** ser ou `top` ou `bottom`. Esse atributo indica que qual direção o seu painel deslizante irá surgir.
> 3. Tenha certeza de que a raiz tenha dois filhos. O **primeiro** filho precisa ser o layout principal. O **segundo** filho é o layout para o painel deslizante.
> 4. O filho que é o layout principal precisa ter os atributos de `width` e `height` como sendo **`match_parent`**. O painel deslizante, o segundo filho, precisa ter o atributo `width` como **`match_parent`** e o atributo `height` ou sendo **`match_parent`** ou a maior altura que deseja.
> 5. Por padrão, o painel inteiro age como uma região "draggable", e irá interceptar por eventos de click e drag. Você pode restringir a área "draggable". Basta em seu `onCreate` ou `onCreateView` especificar uma `View` passando no método `setDragView` ou o atributo `dragView` no seu xml.

Esse é um exemplo de layout usando a *library*, tirado do repositório github:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Uma sugestão para ter uma transição mais suave, isso é, para o painel deslizante ficar por cima da `ActionBar`, terá que usar um atributo em seu tema:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

O resultado será algo como isso, é claro que existem outras configurações, que estão disponíveis na documentação no github<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Exemplo do <code>Android Sliding Up Panel</code>]

Referências:

1. https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: valeu, ajudou muito.

Comment: velho você mim ajudou muito, mas aplicação tá ficando com problema de renderização, o painel não está aparecendo direito. Você tem alguma ideia do que pode ser isso?

Comment: Acho que alguma coisa a ver com o google maps

Comment: Silas, vale a pena criar outra pergunta. Ai vc inclui o código do layout. Pra ver como vc incluiu o Google Maps. Posso inluir meu código que usa o GoogleMaps como um gist e colocar aqui depois, talvez de pra ver a diferença.

Comment: @SilasRibeiro, da uma olhada nesse gist: https://gist.github.com/wakim/eb990978344f13e4cf89. É claro que removi algumas partes porque não são diretamente ligadas ao Sliding Up Panel, se tiver faltando algo é só avisar que eu coloco.