# Navegação Google Maps Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Alguém conhece material de referência para desenvolver um app Android semelhante ao novo formato de navegação e animação do Google Maps?

A ideia é posicionar o InfoWindow do Marker na região de baixo da tela. E assim que o usuário tocar, ou fazer um swipe para cima, este exibir os detalhes completos do local.

Não encontrei nada específico na documentação do Google Developer. Alguma ideia?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Nas [**guidelines** do Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) não tem nada tão específico, mas ele dá alguns padrões de navegação bem genéricos. Para o padrão de "**Sliding Panel**", semelhante ao Google Maps, recomendo olhar essa resposta que fornece uma alternativa para implementa-lo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28086/6436.

Comment: Era exatamente este o efeito desejado, @Wakim, obrigado! Só uma obs: no post mencionado, você disponibiliza um gist que não está mais acessível. Vc poderia me enviar o código que implementa junto ao Maps para eu ter uma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Ah, vou dar uma olhada de porque não esta disponível, qualquer coisa eu pego o código e coloco lá denovo.

Comment: Agradeço muito se vc disponibilizar este código. Vai me ajudar muito!

Comment: Realmente não achei o repositório com o código. Posso montar um repositório no github com um exemplo e te aviso mais tarde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que esteja procurando pelo [**AndroidSlidingUpPanel**](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), é uma biblioteca que fornece um `Widget` com a funcionalidade que procura.

A integração com o **Google Maps** é simples, no meu exemplo eu fiz o acesso a [**Google Places API**](https://developers.google.com/places/android/) para Android. Onde busquei alguns lugares e criei `Markers`, sincronizado com o `SlidingUpPanelLayout`.

Meu layout ficou:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="72dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoAnchorPoint="0.5"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <include layout="@layout/sliding_panel" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Minha Activity ficou:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,
    PlacesListAdapter.ListCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    private PlacesListAdapter mAdapter;
    private PlacesPagerAdater mPagerAdapter;
    private PlacesInfoWindowAdapter mInfoWindowAdapter;

    private List<PlaceLikelihood> mPlaces;
    private List<Marker> mMarkers;

    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener mListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            moveToLocationOneShot(location);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        configureViewPager();
        configureRecyclerView();
        queryForNearbyPlaces();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void configureViewPager() {
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter = new PlacesPagerAdater(this));

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void configureRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new PlacesListAdapter(this).setListCallback(this));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    private void queryForNearbyPlaces() {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                mPlaces = new ArrayList<>(likelyPlaces.getCount());
                mMarkers = new ArrayList<>(likelyPlaces.getCount());
                mInfoWindowAdapter = new PlacesInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this);

                int i = 0;

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    mPlaces.add(placeLikelihood.freeze());
                    mMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(buildMarkerForPlace(placeLikelihood.getPlace(), i++)));
                }

                mAdapter.setData(mPlaces);
                mPagerAdapter.setData(mPlaces);
                mInfoWindowAdapter.setData(mPlaces);

                likelyPlaces.release();

                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mInfoWindowAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    MarkerOptions buildMarkerForPlace(Place place, int position) {
        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();

        mo.position(place.getLatLng());
        mo.title(place.getName().toString());
        mo.snippet(Integer.toString(position));

        return mo;
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(mListener);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mInfoWindowAdapter);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    private void moveToLocationOneShot(Location location) {
        moveToLocation(location);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
    }

    private void moveToLocation(Location location) {
        moveToLocation(getLatLng(location));
    }

    private void moveToLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(latLng, 16f, 0f, 0f)));
    }

    private LatLng getLatLng(Location loc) {
        return new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectionFailed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
        showMarker(mMarkers.get(position));
    }

    void showMarker(Marker marker) {
        moveToLocation(marker.getPosition());
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(View item) {
        int position = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(item);

        mPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
        showMarker(mMarkers.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        int position = mMarkers.indexOf(marker);

        mPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

        return false;
    }
}
```

E não esquecendo das dependências:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
```

É claro que ainda faltam alguns detalhes, mas está com um bom código para começar.

Os demais artefatos, como `Adapters` que foram usados, estão no [repositório do código](https://github.com/wakim/places-api-example).

Comment: Este código é um exato complemento do que estou desenvolvendo. Muito bom, obrigado! Porém, não consegui carregar os locais (e nem encontrei a lista de locais no código), o que faz com que exiba o mapa e o sliding vazio abaixo...

Comment: A consulta aos locais e assim como o preenchimento dos `Adapters` é feita no método `queryForNearbyPlaces`, mais especificamente no método do `Callback`. Se não está retornando nada é porque precisa configurar sua chave de API no console do Google (`Google Places for Android`).

Comment: Sim, o Places API está habilitado e com a chave gerada no console (browser key). Aliás, pelo que entendi, a API_KEY a ser informada no AndroidManifest seria a browser Key (tentei ambas as chaves geradas, Android key e browser key, mas não retornou nada em ambos os casos). É isso mesmo?

Comment: Lá na área de API's tem duas: "Places API" e "Places API for Android", você precisa ativar o segundo. No caso da Key, é a Android Key mesmo, colocando o SHA e o pacote certo. No caso do Android Studio ele gera um SHA automático ao criar o projeto integração com o Google Maps. Dê também uma olhada se tem algum erro no console.

Comment: Nenhum erro no Console, mas eu estava com o serviço errado habilitado. Agora que ajustei estes detalhes da chave e substutuí o serviço para "Places API for Android", a aplicação começou a dar crash, e exibe o erro "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>". O que pode ser?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no **LogCat** pelo stacktrace completo, deve ter dado erro em alguma `View` do layout.

Comment: Era um erro simples de nomenclatura no colors.xml. Tudo resolvido e funcionando! Obrigado @Wakim!